# Error installing tidyverse in R 4.1.1 for windows

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to install the tidyverse package for R 4.1.1 frequently, but unfortunately, always finding an error.

The massage is as follows:

```
Error in install.packages : cannot open file 'c:/users/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/file162476877338/tzdb/tzdata/windowsZones.xml': Invalid argument
```

The similar installation tidyverse (R 4.1.1) in mac is running well. Do you have any solution?

Thank you

Comment: what was the code you tried

Comment: This error seems to be for the `tzdb` package dependency. What is the output you get when you run `install.packages("tzdb")`?

Comment: Hi Mike, The code is as follows: > install.packages("tzdb")
Installing package into ‘\\CNAS.RU.NL/U728217/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/tzdb_0.1.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1411873 bytes (1.3 MB)
downloaded 1.3 MB

Error in install.packages : cannot open file '\\CNAS/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/file3fb0d4cf7a/tzdb/tzdata/windowsZones.xml': Invalid argument

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the UNC (Network) park for the library location, based on your comment of installing `tzdb`. You should try specifying a R lib path that is local, or at least mapped to a drive letter.